# Filter same type of data from api and display on table View

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, filter

(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)
This is my API response
(Focus on userId and id)-

```
    [
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
      },
      {
        "userId": 2,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
        "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
      },
    .
    .
    .
    .
      {
    "userId": 10,
    "id": 100,
    "title": "at nam consequatur ea labore ea harum",
    "body": "cupiditate quo est a modi nesciunt soluta\nipsa voluptas error itaque dicta in\nautem qui minus magnam et distinctio eum\naccusamus ratione error aut"
  }
    ]
```

I am getting UserID - 1, two time from API but I have to display it on TableViewCell only single time...and when I tap Cell of userID - 1 than I have to display corresponding data of userID- 1 that is("id": 1 and "id": 2) on TableView Of AllDataViewController i.e..(NextViewController).

Below Is my Coding part it work fine without Filtering data

ViewController -

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var table:UITableView!
    var listArray = [Post]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadData()
        table.dataSource = self
        table.delegate = self
    }
}
  
extension ViewController{
    // MARK:- TableView Code
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return listArray.count
    }
     
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let mycell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        mycell.detailTextLabel!.text = String(listArray[indexPath.row].userId)
       return mycell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //need code for this method
    }
}

// MARK:- API Calling
extension ViewController{
    // MARK: - Modals
    struct Post:Codable {
        var userId: Int
        var id:Int
        var title:String
        var body:String
    }

    func loadData()
    {
        let strURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
        
        AF.request(strURL, method: .get,encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
            
            switch response.result
            {
            case.success:
                print(response)
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { [self] in
                    
                    if let result = response.data{
                        do
                        {
                            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                            let decodedData = try jsonDecoder.decode([Post].self, from: result)
                            let decoderesult = decodedData
                            self.listArray.append(contentsOf: decoderesult)
                            self.table.reloadData()
                        }
        catch {
            print("Error:",error)
        }
                    }
                  })
                break
            case.failure(let err):
                print("error->",err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AllDataViewController -

```
import UIKit

class AllDataViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var allDataTable: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
}

extension AllDataViewController{
    // MARK:- TableView Code
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
     
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        //need code for this method
        
        let mycell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
//        mycell.detailTextLabel!.text = ???
//        mycell.textLabel!.text = ???
       return mycell
    }
}
```

(1) How can I filter data from API locally, and display data on AllDataViewController corresponding to userID ??

[MY PROJECT LOOK LIKE THIS BY USING ABOVE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tr8b.png)

[THIS IS HOW I NEED MY PROJECT TO LOOK LIKE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSavS.png)

Comment: Use a dictionary, [Int, [Post]] with userId as key and the Post objects for that userId as values or extract all unique userId values to an array and use that array for your table view and then apply a filter on your original array to get the Post objects for a selected userId.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson thanks for your response. Will you help me a little more with coding part?
I will be grateful.

Comment: No, I find your question to broad with these multiple sub-questions

Comment: ok.. @Joakim Danielson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is working code for what you need. I haven’t implemented any architecture, so most of the code is in `ViewController` for your understanding. I hope you can create simple `StoryBoard` design with `tableView` and test the code.

**Note-:** I have a segue from tableView cell of VC1 to VC2 in storyboard.

**VC1-:**

```
  import UIKit

class TestController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var testTableView: UITableView!
    private var filteredData:[User]? = []
    private var selectedUserId:Int?
    
    var UserObjects:[User]?{
        didSet{
            sortedUsers(UserObjects!)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getData {  user, error in
            if error == nil{
                self.UserObjects = user!
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func sortedUsers(_ array:[User]) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { [unowned self] in
            let sortedList = array.sorted(by: {$0.userId < $1.userId})
            self.getSingleObjectForUsres(sortedList)
        }
    }
    
    func getSingleObjectForUsres(_ sortedArray:[User]) {
        filteredData?.append(sortedArray[0])
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { [unowned self] in
            for index in 1..<sortedArray.count{
                if sortedArray[index].userId != sortedArray[index - 1].userId{
                    self.filteredData?.append(sortedArray[index])
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.testTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
}

extension TestController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let filteredData = filteredData else{
            return 0
        }
        return filteredData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TestTableCell
        cell.eventLabel.text = filteredData![indexPath.row].userId.description
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        selectedUserId = filteredData![indexPath.row].userId
        return indexPath
    }
    
}

extension TestController{
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? TestControllerTwo
        guard let users = UserObjects else{
            return
        }
        destinationVC?.userObjects = users
        destinationVC!.selectedUserObjects = selectedUserId!
    }
}

extension TestController{
    var session:URLSession?{
        URLSession.shared
    }
    func getData(completion:
                    @escaping ([User]?, Error?) -> Void)  {
        let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
        let task = session!.dataTask(with: url) {  data, response, error in
            //guard let self = self else { return }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  response.statusCode == 200,
                  error == nil,
                  let data = data else {
                completion(nil,error)
                return
            }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let users = try decoder.decode([User].self, from: data)
                completion(users,nil)
            } catch let error{
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
}

struct User:Decodable,Hashable{
    
    var userId:Int
    var id:Int
    var title:String
    var body:String
    
    init(userId:Int,id:Int,title:String,body:String) {
        self.userId = userId
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
}
```

**VC2-:**

```
import UIKit

class TestControllerTwo: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var testTableView2: UITableView!
    var userObjects:[User] = []
    var selectedUserObjects:Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        filterUsers()
    }
    
    func filterUsers(){
        userObjects = userObjects.filter{$0.userId == selectedUserObjects}
        testTableView2.reloadData()
    }
    
    @IBAction func addEventAndPop(_ sender: Any) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
}

extension TestControllerTwo:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userObjects.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1")
        cell?.textLabel!.text = userObjects[indexPath.row].id.description
        return cell!
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
}
```

**Output-:**

[image][image]

Comment: This one is Perfect solution that I need ..Thanks @Tushar Sharma

Comment: @Sarthak Please upvote and click the check mark button, if the answer was helpful.

Comment: I have marked this solution useful...And one more thing..how can i display title and body  along with id on VC2?

Comment: Just display in cellForRow method in VC2, you already have array of objects, just like id you can display remaining values on different labels.Create your own custom TableViewCell class for this.

Comment: OK ....DONE....